# laravel Target class [TestController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I use Laravel Framework 9.31.0 on  win11

I used action syntax in the file routes\web.php:

```
Route::get('role', [TestController::class, 'index']);
```

or full path to controller:

```
=> 'app\Http\Controllers\TestController@index'
```

or like this:

```
use app\Http\Controllers\TestController;
```

Also I declared variable $namespace in the file app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php
and told laravel to use that for our web and api routes:

```
class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public const HOME = '/home';
    protected $namespace = 'app\\Http\\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::middleware('api')
                ->prefix('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

Nothing helps. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not post images of your code. **Code is Text**; please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73871263/edit) and include your code as properly formatted text. Also, do you have a `TestController.php` in `app\Http\Controllers`? Also make sure it has the proper namespace, which should be `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`. You currently have `app\Http\Controllers`, which might be an issue (`app` vs `App`)

Comment: did you try composer dump?  Check the lettercase of your controller file. Check the class name of your controller. Check the controller namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
use App\Http\Controllers\TestController;
```

respect characters

i hope it was useful

Comment: It didn't help. Getting the same error:: laravel Target class [TestController] does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Export the TestController Path using his correct namespace.

Comment: I am new to Laravel. Can you provide an example of how to do this?

Answer (score -2):

Based on the code you posted, you have to do this:

```php
Route::get('role', 'TestController@index');
```

Your `namespace` should be `protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';` (see `App` instead of `app`). I would still recommend to use the new way Laravel routing system works, do not use a namespace in your route service provider and just use the FQDN on your route file

---

If they are using `->namespace($this->namespace)`, they must use the old way = `'TestController@index'`.

Comment: It didn't help. Getting the same error:: laravel Target class [TestController] does not exist

Comment: @ViliusGaidelis try following this from the official documentation for Laravel 9: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#the-default-route-files. If that does not help, try Laravel this one from Laravel 7: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#basic-routing